# Finding the closed form of an infinite series

Tags: limits, summation

Consider the infinite series $$S=\sum^\infty_{j=0} \frac{\cos{\left((2j+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}}{(2j+1)^2 \exp((2j+1)^2)}$$ Is there any way I could find the closed form expression? I have considered the limit of this $$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{j=0} \frac{\cos{\left((2j+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}}{(2j+1)^2\exp((2j+1)^2)}$$ but I don't know how to evaluate this summation.

Comment: I changed {\rm exp} to \exp.  That provides proper spacing in expressions like $a\exp b$, just as with \log, \cos, etc. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: One could eliminate the cosine ...

Comment: One should not eliminate the cosine. If the sum doesn't contain the $(2j+1)^2$ factor in denominator, the
sum will have the form of [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). As a result, the sum can be rewritten
as an integral of the form:

$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\cos\big((2j+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\big)}{(2j+1)^2\exp\big((2j+1)^2 s\big)}
= \frac12 \int_s^\infty \vartheta_2\left( \frac{\pi}{4}, e^{-4t} \right) dt
$$
However, how to evaluate the last integral is completely beyond me.